# ModuleNotFoundError: __path__ attribute not found on 'guessing_game' while trying to find 'guessing_game.py'

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror

I wrote a simple Python program 'guessing_game.py'. When I try to run this code in the command prompt using `python -m guessing_game.py`, the program runs fine, but in the end, it says:

> Error while finding module specification for 'guessing_game.py'
> (ModuleNotFoundError: **path** attribute not found on 'guessing_game'
> while trying to find 'guessing_game.py').

When I run the same program using `python -guessing_game.py`, it runs fine, and it doesn't show that message as well.

Comment: `-m` takes a module name, not a file path, and `.py` isn't part of the module name.

Answer (score 4):

Because you're trying to run it as a module?

From https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m

> -m `<module-name>`
>
> Search [sys.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) for the named module and execute its contents as the [`__main__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html#module-__main__) module.
>
> Since the argument is a module name, you must not give a file
> extension (.py). The module name should be a valid absolute Python
> module name, but the implementation may not always enforce this (e.g.
> it may allow you to use a name that includes a hyphen).

Comment: I get that -m searches sys.path for the named module, but could you please elaborate what do you mean by "execute its contents as main module"